# Using mixed A-Type and CNAME

Tags: domains, google-analytics, google-search-console, subdomain, cname

```
A (IPv4 Adresszeiger)
doc.domain.de.      IN  A   301 to domain.atlassian.net 
jira.domain.de.     IN  A   23.23.xx.xx 
domain.de.          IN  A   301 to www.domain.de    
work.domain.de.     IN  A   23.23.xx.xx 
www.domain.de.      IN  A   46.252.xx.xx    
CNAME (Canonical name)
source.domain.de.   IN  CNAME   bitbucket.org.  
test.domain.de.     IN  CNAME   domain.force.com.
```

Found this today at a customers domain settings.

Planning on adding Google Analytics and Webmaster Tools. Will there be any problems with this setup?

Could there be any problems with all these confusing redirects? `46.252.xx.xx` is the webspace host.

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics shouldn't care that the IP addresses are different for different subdomains, or even that it is using DNS CNAME vs A records.

You may have issues with:

- Putting your analytics tracking code onto all of those servers.  The software running each subdomain will have to be able to serve up the analytics code.
- Tracking `domain.atlassain.net` since that isn't a subdomain, but rather on a totally different top level domain.